# Use a locally stored .jar file as a dependency in a Maven project: compile class files

Tags: java, maven

I'm a relative Maven novice and am having difficulties using a locally stored jar as a module within my IntelliJ project - a project I have taken from an online tutorial.

I've brought it into my .m2 folder using:

```
mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=C:/../resources/myshop-automatedtestscore 3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar" "-DpomFile=C:/../resources/myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.pom --Dsources=C:/../myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar"
```

.jar is located at:

```
C:\Users\daveb\.m2\repository\com\myshop\automatedtests\myshop-automatedtestscore\3.1.7-SNAPSHOT\3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And I added the dependency in the main pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.myshop.automatedtests</groupId>
      <artifactId>myshop-automatedtestscore</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.17-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I go to Project Structure -> Libraries, I can see the Sources dependency jar file is there in grey so should be fine. However the core project seems to be unable to access the class versions of the file.  In Target folder they remain .class but in External libraries they are .java

[image]

Apologies if this is a novice or obvious solution.  I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: Can you provide the exact name and the location (within .m2) of your `jar` file?

Comment: Sure: C:\Users\daveb\.m2\repository\com\amyshop\automatedtests\myshop-automatedtestscore\3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

You have to install jar using below command -

mvn install:install-file -Dfile= -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=

You have to give artifacts and other parameters so that you will be able to use in pom file using below code -

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you have to complie your project so that this dependency will be added in your project.

mvn eclipse:eclipse
mvn clean install

Comment: thank you; I already did that. Sorry, my question was not clear.  Doing a mvn clean install does not work.  I am using IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

You can press here to force refresh the plugins in Intelij.

[image: Refresh]

Here you can check which repository you have and also which maven you have.
[image: Maven settings] Click on preferences

Another option you have is to perform this :

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dependency is

```
<groupId>com.me.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-example</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
```

Then your jar file would be `my-example-1.1.0.jar` and it will be under *\.m2\repository\com\me\example\my-example\1.1.0\my-example-1.1.0.jar*.

In your case, your `jar` file is `myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar` and it should be under

*C:\Users\daveb.m2\repository\com\myshop\automatedtests\myshop-automatedtestscore\3.1.17-SNAPSHOT\myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar*.

After this, do a `Maven > Reimport` from IntelliJ.

Comment: thank you.  Sorry, I am not helping myself here.  The path is in fact as you stated and I have updated the original question; apologies. I have done a Maven Reimport but no joy.  Should I have to manually unarchive the jar file (as I did originally)?  I think not and should probably re-start from scratch

Comment: Is `3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar` the name of your `jar` file? If so, the dependency you added is not correct.

Comment: I think the issue was that I was not bringing in the sources.  I have now done that and updated the question but the issue seems to persist.  I think I just need to run the correct Maven goal to generate the sources or consume them within the main module

Comment: Try this: Rename your `jar` file to this: `myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar` and keep this outside .m2 folder. Open cmd at this location. Run this command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myshop-automatedtestscore-3.1.17-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.myshop.automatedtests -DartifactId=myshop-automatedtestscore -Dversion=3.1.17-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar`. Now the `jar` should be installed at the location I mentioned in my anwser. Put the dependency you provided in your answer in `pom.xml` and reimport. Edit: Before you try this, delete folder tree starting from myshop

Comment: Hi Andy, I do have the jar as a dependency in my .m2 and can see it in external libraries within IntelliJ.  But, I don't understand why I can't compile these .java files and use them in my project